# Unit Testing - how much more time does it really add?

Tags: unit-testing

I have heard that writing (coding) unit tests for your application effectively doubles the development time required for projects. Is this true, particularly for beginners?

Also some follow-up questions (brownie points):
If you were doing a client project that you hand off when finished, is it worth the time and effort to do unit testing?

Comment: Thank for the answers so far. Sorry forgot to add that the language I am using is PHP, and some CakePHP framework. However, I meant for this  to be more of a general question to get a variety of answers. I am also interested in learning Ruby, and Objective-C.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would say that double the time is a fair estimate and yes, unit testing is ***always*** worth the time and effort.

However I would contend that the time spent in unit testing is significantly less then the time it would take to debug and fix errors later that resulted from a lack of unit testing.

Comment: except: when tests are written but not maintained.

Comment: The reason why it is worth it is that it decreases the amount of time spend debugging. With a decent coverage of the lower layers of the logic, many guesses and odd-balls are out of the way when debugging the app. Reason to mention the lower layers, is that sometimes writing unit test for higher level stuff requires a lot of prep, of injection of stuff that is not available etc. So do cover the easier stuff for sure.

Comment: Without unit tests, no refactoring. Without refactoring, no (easily) maintainable code. Just for this, unit tests are essential.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent - exactly, it's not even a choice IMO. Without unit tests even small changes to the code could introduce hidden bugs, let alone major refactors.

Comment: @MitchWheat - it's not worth the effort if your program is for internal use only or just for you, or even if you have less client than you can count on one hand. I also find it takes a **considerable** long time to write **proper** unit tests which attack every possible scenario. sometimes even x4 times more.

Comment: @vsync: I agree partially with your comment: writing tests can be laborious. The problem is that from experience we all know that that software that is written "for internal use" often goes on to production. Rather than try to get 100% coverage with unit tests, add integration tests to the overall testing.

Comment: @MitchWheat - if you get paid to code I guess you get paid to writing tests. I am a free man, nobody pays me extra to sit and spend x3 time writing tests unless I argue with the client it is a must. many times in life you put money considerations above spending ("wasting") time doing a laborious thing that probably won't benefit you personally in financial terms.

Comment: @vsync: you are totally missing the point. When you write code IT WILL HAVE BUGS! No matter how good or experienced you are. Tests help provide a layer of confidence that code is working as expected. Are your clients happy with buggy code? NO!

Comment: not all bugs means loosing money from the product. you can always fix it when you see it or when it is submitted to you by another. if you are very good, you minimize the risk considerably. I know that you are angry and cannot believe somebody can be that good, but there are very good programmers that have zero-risk bugs, which means the bugs they do make do not affect the earning of the product. that is a reasonable thing to conclude.

Answer (score 9):

> writing (coding) unit tests for your
>   application effectively doubles the
>   development time required for
>   projects.

Writing tests is definitely slower than writing no tests at all if you just count the time typing out code. However if you factor in time for breaking existing functionality-debugging-fixing without the safety net of tests, the benefits will generally outweigh the costs for anything other than trivial projects. Tests aid you with Design (TDD) + Defense (Regression) + Documentation (Specs).

> Is this true, particularly
>   for beginners?

It depends. To paraphrase Beck (I think), if you're a dunce, tools/meth won't help you, if you're a coding-God, you probably don't need them. However for most of us in the middle, it helps. As you move towards the right on that spectrum, things become second nature to you, you being to 'see' whats coming and time-taken begins to reduce (although not to 0). To avoid making rookie mistakes, find someone who's already been there (get help from a mailing list or hire a good coach for a while)

> Also some follow-up questions (brownie points): If you were doing a client project that 
>   you hand off when finished, is it worth the time and effort to do unit testing?

Even if the next team chucked the test suite, I'd still do it to keep my productivity up and reduce time spent creating and chasing bugs.

Comment: +1. The first part summarized what I wanted to add to Andrew Hare's answer. As the project gets bigger, having unit tests around would greatly aid testing and debugging. The development time is longer without unit tests for non-trivial projects.

Comment: "To paraphrase Beck (I think), [...]": yes it was Beck, in the introduction of *TDD by example*. I've read it two days ago but seems to be something that you end up remembering for longer :)

Answer (score 6):

Not if you're using TDD because:

- You actually write your test first. This is itself is a big time saver, since you've laid what you're setting out to do. You also know exactly when to stop coding. (When the test passes)
- When you actually write the code, it winds up being as small as possible. You can stop coding when you pass the test, and you can then make it better confidently as long as the test is still passing.
- Then write tests for the edge cases (if necessary) and check the would be problems.

I've done this and found this actually cuts down dev time - because you're already thought about what you want to do before you even start writing the actual code, and you know when when you've done it that it actually works.

Answer (score 4):

Unit tests also serve the purpose of documenting your code base, in terms of how do I use/call a particular class/method.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends... on what amount of test coverage are you targeting

If you intend to follow the true definition of TDD where each and every line of code is tested via unit test cases- you may be looking for huge effort

But it doesn't have to be that

You can find your own balance...

In my experiences- I haven't find this to double the time- though it does add a factor (20-25% ?)

I mean- even if you didn't have unit test cases- you would still do manually unit test it- right ?

Over the time of the project- you will see that the time spent on unit test cases is recvered quite easily

For client projects- IMHO yes. They will hopefully appreciate the effort

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that time to write automated unit tests varies based on your language and how you do your development.  For example, writing C# with a very procedural style can lead to difficult to develop tests.  However, if you take a different approach, say using some mocking and IOC frameworks, unit testing time can drastically be reduced.

Answer (score 2):

On the topic of added time, since you mentioned you're a beginner: the sooner you can find a unit testing suite that fits your needs, the better.  You haven't mentioned what language you're using, but if there is no support for reflection (C, C++ for example), it's generally going to take a lot longer to set up the unit testing facilities, because you have to instantiate the TestSuite, and the Test, and you have to register the Test, etc.  That's all a lot of stuff to learn when all  you want to do is run a couple tests!

On the other hand, if you're using a more dynamic language like Python, for instance, you can pretty much set up unit tests with hardly any knowledge of unit testing by making a few `testXXX` methods with the `unittest` module.

Regarding the second question, put yourself in the shoes of the client - wouldn't you like to hear that the product you've bought has been thoroughly tested?  They (probably) love numbers!  Tell them that you've set up automated testing, there were over 500 individual tests run, over 80% of the code has been tested that way -- well, only tell them the truth, but you get the point.  It adds an immense value in the way of code confidence, and frankly I'd rather do business with someone who can demonstrate that they *know* what has been tested and what might be flaky, rather than someone who just hands me something and says "it's done."

Comment: Good insights, thank you for answering the second question as well.

Comment: Just speaking from experience here, and you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For my programming, I tend to only test that parts of the code that I can't intuitively look at and know it's going to work (which some people will argue isn't enough, but that's neither here nor there).

I've been programming that way a long time, and that I use those tests to help me write my code in the first place. Given that, the time to write my tests add, basically, nothing to my overall development time. If I skipped writing the tests I do, it "might" save me 10% of my time overall, if that.

When I first started using automated testing, I'd say a doubling over the overall time to write code is a fair estimate. But, over time, I've gotten to where I am not (adding next to no time). Honestly, it's something you get used to and it becomes part of how you design your code in the first place.

Edit: It occurs to me to add that there are times when writing the test code still adds a fair amount of time to my coding, sometimes well more than double. That being said, those times are few and far between as I tend to avoid code that does so... it's a code smell to me.

Answer (score 2):

If youre serious about unit testing I would recommend the book [The art of unit testing](http://www.artofunittesting.com/) by [Roy Osherove](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/).

Answer (score 1):

What you are testing will determine how long it takes. For example, it takes me much longer to write a unit test for TSQL using the Database unit test framework from MS than it took to write the stored procedure, as it is a very manual process to prepare the test.

But, if I use Eclipse or VS2008 for Java or C# classes, and I just tell it to create the tests, then it is pretty quick to do the tests, as much of the grunt work is done for me.

It is always worth it though, as it helps to cut down on some likely bugs, but, more importantly, when it comes to duplicating a bug you will end up writing these tests anyway, and if you don't design your classes to be unit-testable then it will require refactoring, which can introduce new bugs, in order to fix a reported bug.

That is one important thing is that you will find that you have functions that are not testable, so you will end up refactoring just so you can do reasonable unit tests.

For example, if you have a function that selects from a database, then does business logic on the results, how do you properly test that?  It should be two separate functions, with a controller that calls to fetch the data, then calls to do the business logic, so you will have three tests, but, the controller can go to a mock for the database as you have a separate test to test the database layer.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on benefit you are getting. It is a complete waste of time for conventional web apps - clients will bitch more about messed up ui, rather than code slowly corrupting data.